# Simplifying code for testing directory content/files

Tags: java, testing, assertj

I have the following test code which checks the content of a particular directory structure

```
assertThat(install_should_not_fail).isDirectory().satisfies(isnf -> {
  assertThat(new File(isnf, "maven-metadata-local.xml")).isNotEmpty();
  assertThat(new File(isnf, "1.0")).isDirectory().satisfies(v10 -> {
    assertThat(v10).satisfies(file -> {
      assertThat(new File(file, "install_should_not_fail-1.0.jar")).isNotEmpty();
      assertThat(new File(file, "install_should_not_fail-1.0.pom")).isNotEmpty();
      assertThat(new File(file, "_remote.repositories")).isNotEmpty();
    });
  });
});
```

and I have several tests which do very similar things. The question is: Can that be made simpler  (I know I could refactor out a method which contains exactly that code) but I'm interested more in getting the above code simpler using AssertJ if it's possible?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest an approach that does not use `satisfies` to avoid the nested blocks:

```java
assertThat(install_should_not_fail).isDirectory();
assertThat(new File(install_should_not_fail, "maven-metadata-local.xml")).isNotEmpty();

File v10 = new File(install_should_not_fail, "1.0");
assertThat(v10).isDirectory();
assertThat(new File(v10, "install_should_not_fail-1.0.jar")).isNotEmpty();
assertThat(new File(v10, "install_should_not_fail-1.0.pom")).isNotEmpty();
assertThat(new File(v10, "_remote.repositories")).isNotEmpty();
```

I feel this makes the code a bit lighter and more readable (to me at least).

Moreover, I think this is a good candidate for soft assertions so that all the assertions errors are reported instead of failing at the first one.

Comment: many thanks for your suggestions. The funny thing is that I came exactly from such a solution which I replaced with the one in my questions which represents (from my point of view) the structure of a directory. But of course this solution is lighter..I have a large number of them https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/blob/master/itf-maven-plugin/src/test/java/com/soebes/itf/maven/plugin/BasicIT.java And you suggestion about soft assertions is a very good idea. I need to reconsider my needs and may be I should check for a custom assertions (also suggested by Marcin...

Comment: if you have a lot of tests with this pattern then I agree with Marcin that investing in custom assertions is good option (but bear in mind that you will have to maintain them).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to check whether the files are non-empty, [Files::fileNamesIn](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/util/Files.html) may come handy. You could do something like:

```java
assertThat(Files.filesNamesIn(dir, /* recursive */ true)).contains(
  basePath + "/maven-metadata-local.xml",
  basePath + "/1.0/install_should_not_fail-1.0.jar",
  basePath + "/1.0/install_should_not_fail-1.0.pom",
  basePath + "/1.0/_remote.repositories")
```

Otherwise you may refactor this pattern into your own custom assertion. For example, here is an assertion that verifies that the given paths represent non-empty, readable files inside a directory:

```java
public class MyAssertions extends Assertions {
    public static MyFileAssert assertThat(File actual) {
        return MyFileAssert.assertThat(actual);
    }
}

public class MyFileAssert extends AbstractFileAssert<MyFileAssert> {
    public MyFileAssert(File actual) {
        super(actual, MyFileAssert.class);
    }

    public static MyFileAssert assertThat(File actual) {
        return new MyFileAssert(actual);
    }

    public MyFileAssert containsReadableNonEmptyFiles(String... paths) {
        isDirectory();

        List<String> nonExistent = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> nonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> nonReadable = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> empty = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String path : paths) {
            File file = new File(actual, path);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                nonExistent.add(path);
                continue;
            }

            if (!file.isFile()) {
                nonFiles.add(path);
                continue;
            }

            if (!file.canRead()) {
                nonReadable.add(path);
                continue;
            }

            if (file.length() == 0) {
                empty.add(path);
            }
        }

        if (!(nonExistent.isEmpty() && nonFiles.isEmpty() && nonReadable.isEmpty() && empty.isEmpty())) {
            StringBuilder failMessage = new StringBuilder()
                    .append("Expected directory '")
                    .append(actual)
                    .append("' to contain the following readable, non-empty files:\n");

            for (String path : paths) {
                failMessage.append("  ")
                        .append(path)
                        .append("\n");
            }


            if (!nonExistent.isEmpty()) {
                failMessage.append("The following files don't exist:\n");

                for (String path : nonExistent) {
                    failMessage.append("  ")
                            .append(path)
                            .append("\n");
                }

            }

            // The rest left out for brevity.

            failWithMessage(failMessage.toString());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

The example usage of the above is as follows:

```java
assertThat(install_should_not_fail).containsReadableNonEmptyFiles(
  "maven-metadata-local.xml",
  "1.0/install_should_not_fail-1.0.jar",
  "1.0/install_should_not_fail-1.0.pom",
  "1.0/_remote.repositories")
```

You may read more about AssertJ's custom assertions [here](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-custom-assertions.html#custom-soft-assertions).

Comment: A custom assertions might be the way I need to consider ....Thanks anyway for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but could always help future users, since 3.13.0 of assertj you have can use [`isEmptyDirectory`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractPathAssert.html#isEmptyDirectory()) and [`isDirectoryContaining`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractPathAssert.html#isDirectoryContaining(java.util.function.Predicate)) to check directory content and since 3.19.0 [`isEmptyFile`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractPathAssert.html#isEmptyFile()) that checks if your file is empty